# Converting text to real numbers in excel

Tags: excel

I have a column that was imported from .txt file. It appears that it contains text that looks like numbers. Is there a way to actually convert them in real numbers? I've already tried formatting the cells as numbers, =Value function, text-to-column thing, though none of them seem to work. Google doesn't spit out anything else. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: If it's a text column, just find and replace `,` with `.` and then convert to Number.

Comment: Unless he's in a country where that is the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Convert Text To Columns" utility on step 2 there is an "Advanced" button.  There you can specify the decimal and "thousands" separators.  This will perform the conversion you desire.

Answer (score 1):

If comma (,) is a decimal separator in your country, and Excel does not recognize the numbers, then your data is formatted as text.

To quickly convert it to numbers you may multiply the whole column by 1 (shortcuts provided for English version of Excel):

- put 1 in a single empty cell and copy that cell (**Ctrl + C**)
- select your range with "texted" numbers
- use Paste Special-> Paste Values -> Multiply (**Ctrl + Alt + V**, then press **V**, then press **M**, then press **Enter**)

(Alternatively, you may use formula like **=A1 * 1** in the adjacent range).

With this **multplication trick** Excel will automatically convert all the values in the destination range to numbers.

If you use a different symbol as a decimal separator e. g. a dot(.) - you shall replace comma with a dot(.) first, as Mako212 suggested.